# Android parse JsonArray of strings don't work

Tags: android, json, list, parsing, object

I've got this parser :

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

            try {
                // Parsing json object response
                // response will be a json object










                ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();

                JSONArray configJsonArray = response.getJSONArray("horaires");
                for(int configIterator = 0; configIterator < configJsonArray.length(); configIterator++){



                    Horaires horaires = new Horaires();
                    JSONObject innerConfigObj = configJsonArray.getJSONObject(configIterator);
                     configGrade = innerConfigObj.getString("heure");
                    horaires.setHeure(configGrade);
                    listdata.clear();

                    JSONArray jr = configJsonArray.getJSONObject(configIterator).getJSONArray("passages");





                    for(int v = 0; v < jr.length(); v++){




                        listdata.add(jr.getString(v));
                        horaires.setPassages(listdata);
                    }


                    horairesList.add(horaires);

                }












            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }


    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // hide the progress dialog

        }
    });
```

And i want him to parse this type of Json :

```
{"arret":{"codeArret":"BRTA1","libelle":"Bretagne","accessible":true},"ligne":{"numLigne":"3","directionSens1":"Marcel Paul","directionSens2":"Neustrie","accessible":true,"etatTrafic":1,"libelleTrafic":"Service normal"},"codeCouleur":"J","plageDeService":"Des horaires adapt\u00e9s aux rythmes de vos journ\u00e9es\r\nEn p\u00e9riode scolaire...\r\nJour rose : du lundi au vendredi (hors 10 mai).\r\nJour vert : les samedis.\r\nJour bleu : les dimanches et jours f\u00e9ri\u00e9s (aucun service le 1er mai).\r\nPendant les vacances scolaires...\r\nJour jaune : du lundi au vendredi (hors vacances de Toussaint).","horaires":[{"heure":"5h","passages":["14","34","54"]},{"heure":"6h","passages":["12","21","31","40","49","58"]},{"heure":"7h","passages":["05","12","19","26","33","40","46","53"]},{"heure":"8h","passages":["00","07","14","21","28","35","42","49","56"]},{"heure":"9h","passages":["03","10","17","23","30","37","44","51","58"]},{"heure":"10h","passages":["05","12","19","26","33","40","47","54"]},{"heure":"11h","passages":["01","08","15","22","29","36","43","50","57"]},{"heure":"12h","passages":["04","11","17","24","31","37","44","53"]},{"heure":"13h","passages":["00","06","13","19","25","31","37","43","49","55"]},{"heure":"14h","passages":["01","07","13","19","25","31","37","43","49","55"]},{"heure":"15h","passages":["01","07","13","19","25","30","36","42","48","54"]},{"heure":"16h","passages":["00","06","12","18","24","30","36","42","48","54"]},{"heure":"17h","passages":["00","06","13","19","25","31","37","43","49","54"]},{"heure":"18h","passages":["00","06","12","18","24","30","36","42","48","54"]},{"heure":"19h","passages":["00","06","12","19","26","33","39","43","49","54"]},{"heure":"20h","passages":["01","09","13","21","30","39","43","52"]},{"heure":"21h","passages":["01","10","20","30","40","50"]},{"heure":"22h","passages":["00","10","20","32","42"]},{"heure":"23h","passages":["02","32"]},{"heure":"0h","passages":["02","32"]}],"prochainsHoraires":[{"heure":"22h","passages":["00"]},{"heure":"22h","passages":["10"]}]}
```

But it give me in each row of the list View same data for the passages so if someone know how to fix this it ould be very nice of him ! Thank you !

Comment: Use GSON and create a class that would read only "horaires"
If you want can use GSON, I will post this as answer and with more details

Comment: This is not all of the code i cut just this part !  I use volley it's work well and i don't want to create another class just for horaires because the parse of the hours work already well :/

Comment: create new listdata don't use listdata.clear();

Answer (score 0):

Use **gson** lib (it's google lib), it's best way and easer to parse any jsonObject. **Gson** is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java object. Gson can work with arbitrary Java objects including pre-existing objects that you do not have source-code of.

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/
or
https://github.com/google/gson

**example:**

```
Map jsonJavaRootObject = new Gson().fromJson("{/*whatever your mega complex object*/}", Map.class)
```

Comment: Please check the 1st and 2nd comment on question

Comment: i answered before these comments or i didn't see it... However. i gave him where he can find gson and who to use it...

Answer (score 0):

Change: `ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();` to `List<Horaires> listdata = new ArrayList<Horaires>();`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily parse the json by simply writing few lines of code. Please find the code below which i have done to get the data from your json to the data structure which is defined below:

```
public class JsonDataVo {
    String codeArret;
    String libelle;
    boolean accessible;
    int numLigne;
    String directionSens1;
    String directionSens2;
    boolean ligneAccessible;
    int etatTrafic;
    String libelleTrafic;
    String codeCouleur;
    String plageDeService;
    ArrayList<HeureDataVO> horaires = new ArrayList<HeureDataVO>();
    ArrayList<HeureDataVO> prochainsHoraires = new ArrayList<HeureDataVO>();

    public String getCodeArret() {
        return codeArret;
    }
    public void setCodeArret(String codeArret) {
        this.codeArret = codeArret;
    }
    public String getLibelle() {
        return libelle;
    }
    public void setLibelle(String libelle) {
        this.libelle = libelle;
    }
    public  boolean getAccessible() {
        return accessible;
    }
    public void setAccessible(  boolean accessible) {
        this.accessible = accessible;
    }
    public int getNumLigne() {
        return numLigne;
    }
    public void setNumLigne(int numLigne) {
        this.numLigne = numLigne;
    }
    public String getDirectionSens1() {
        return directionSens1;
    }
    public void setDirectionSens1(String directionSens1) {
        this.directionSens1 = directionSens1;
    }
    public String getDirectionSens2() {
        return directionSens2;
    }
    public void setDirectionSens2(String directionSens2) {
        this.directionSens2 = directionSens2;
    }
    public boolean isLigneAccessible() {
        return ligneAccessible;
    }
    public void setLigneAccessible(boolean ligneAccessible) {
        this.ligneAccessible = ligneAccessible;
    }
    public int getEtatTrafic() {
        return etatTrafic;
    }
    public void setEtatTrafic(int etatTrafic) {
        this.etatTrafic = etatTrafic;
    }
    public String getLibelleTrafic() {
        return libelleTrafic;
    }
    public void setLibelleTrafic(String libelleTrafic) {
        this.libelleTrafic = libelleTrafic;
    }
    public String getCodeCouleur() {
        return codeCouleur;
    }
    public void setCodeCouleur(String codeCouleur) {
        this.codeCouleur = codeCouleur;
    }
    public String getPlageDeService() {
        return plageDeService;
    }
    public void setPlageDeService(String plageDeService) {
        this.plageDeService = plageDeService;
    }
    public ArrayList<HeureDataVO> getHoraires() {
        return horaires;
    }
    public void setHoraires(ArrayList<HeureDataVO> horaires) {
        this.horaires = horaires;
    }
    public ArrayList<HeureDataVO> getProchainsHoraires() {
        return prochainsHoraires;
    }
    public void setProchainsHoraires(ArrayList<HeureDataVO> prochainsHoraires) {
        this.prochainsHoraires = prochainsHoraires;
    }

}

public class HeureDataVO {
    String heure;
    ArrayList<Integer> passages = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public String getHeure() {
        return heure;
    }
    public void setHeure(String heure) {
        this.heure = heure;
    }
    public ArrayList<Integer> getPassages() {
        return passages;
    }
    public void setPassages(ArrayList<Integer> passages) {
        this.passages = passages;
    }
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getPassages(JSONObject jsonObj){
         ArrayList<Integer> tmpValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        try {
            JSONArray arrayOfValues = jsonObj.getJSONArray("passages");
            for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfValues.length(); i++){
                tmpValues.add(arrayOfValues.getInt(i));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tmpValues;
    }

public JsonDataVo parseJson(JSONObject response){
        JsonDataVo jsonDataVo = new JsonDataVo();
        try {
            JSONObject arretobj = response.getJSONObject("arret");
            jsonDataVo.setCodeArret(arretobj.getString("codeArret"));
            jsonDataVo.setLibelle(arretobj.getString("libelle"));
            jsonDataVo.setAccessible(arretobj.getBoolean("accessible"));
            JSONObject lingeObject = response.getJSONObject("ligne");
            jsonDataVo.setNumLigne(lingeObject.getInt("numLigne"));
            jsonDataVo.setDirectionSens1(lingeObject.getString("directionSens1"));
            jsonDataVo.setDirectionSens2(lingeObject.getString("directionSens2"));
            jsonDataVo.setLigneAccessible(lingeObject.getBoolean("accessible"));
            jsonDataVo.setEtatTrafic(lingeObject.getInt("etatTrafic"));
            jsonDataVo.setLibelleTrafic(lingeObject.getString("libelleTrafic"));
            jsonDataVo.setCodeCouleur(response.getString("codeCouleur"));
            jsonDataVo.setPlageDeService(response.getString("plageDeService"));
            JSONArray horairesArray = response.getJSONArray("horaires");
            for(int i = 0; i < horairesArray.length(); i++){

                JSONObject horairesJsonObject = horairesArray.getJSONObject(i);
                   HeureDataVO tmp = new HeureDataVO();
                   tmp.setHeure(horairesJsonObject.getString("heure"));
                   tmp.setPassages(getPassages(horairesJsonObject));
                   jsonDataVo.getHoraires().add(tmp);
            }

            JSONArray prochainsHorairesArray = response.getJSONArray("horaires");
            for(int i = 0; i < prochainsHorairesArray.length(); i++){

                JSONObject horairesJsonObject = prochainsHorairesArray.getJSONObject(i);
                   HeureDataVO tmp = new HeureDataVO();
                   tmp.setHeure(horairesJsonObject.getString("heure"));
                   tmp.setPassages(getPassages(horairesJsonObject));
                   jsonDataVo.getProchainsHoraires().add(tmp);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonDataVo;
    }
```

I hope this will help you to get the solution you wanted and you will not require any library to parse the json.